# Can not serialize my class to the desired json file

Tags: c#, json.net, actions-on-google

I use for the deserialization and serialization the Newtonsoft.Json Library. I am trying to serialize a C# class to json, I have already serialize many classes to json but I never have came across with such a json file. The problems are that the first "text" attribute doesn't follow up by a open bracket and also that the "platform" attribute repeated (already exist) in fulfillmentMessage.

My Class:

```
    public class Fulfillmentmessage
    {
        public string platform { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("simpleResponses ", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public Simpleresponses simpleResponses { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("basicCard", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]    
        public Basiccard basicCard { get; set; }
    }

    public class Simpleresponses
    {
        public Simplerespons[] simpleResponses { get; set; }
    }

    public class Simplerespons
    {
        public string textToSpeech { get; set; }
    }

    public class Texts
    {
        public Text text { get; set; }
    }

    public class Text
    {
        public List<string> text { get; set; }
    }

    public class Basiccard
    {
        public string title { get; set; }
        public string subtitle { get; set; }
        public string formattedText { get; set; }
        public Image image { get; set; }
        public Button[] buttons { get; set; }
    }

    public class Image
    {
        public string imageUri { get; set; }
        public string accessibilityText { get; set; }
    }

    public class Button
    {
        public string title { get; set; }
        public Openuriaction openUriAction { get; set; }
    }

    public class Openuriaction
    {
        public string uri { get; set; }
    }
```

expected result:

```
{
    "fulfillmentMessages": [
      {
        "platform": "ACTIONS_ON_GOOGLE",
        "simpleResponses": {
          "simpleResponses": [
            {
              "textToSpeech": "Did you meant?"
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "text": {
          "text": [
            "Did you meant?"
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "platform": "ACTIONS_ON_GOOGLE",
        "basicCard": {
          "title": "Title",
          "subtitle": "Subtitle",
          "formattedText": "A text to enter here is nn hiusn uboub bubub mio",
          "image": {
            "imageUri": "https://www.eg.com",
            "accessibilityText": "Accessibility Text"
          },
          "buttons": [
            {
              "title": "Weblink Title",
              "openUriAction": {
                "uri": "https://www.eg.com"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
}
```

actual result:

```
{
"fulfillmentMessages": [
    {
        "platform": "ACTIONS_ON_GOOGLE",
        "simpleResponses": {
            "simpleResponses": [
            {
                "textToSpeech": "Test fulfillment Text"
             }
            ]
        },
        "text": {
            "text": [
                "Test fulfillment Text"
                ]
            },
            "basicCard": {
                "title": "Test Title",
                "subtitle": "Test subtitle",
                "formattedText": "Test Discription",
                "image": {
                    "imageUri": "https://www.eg.com",
                    "accessibilityText": "Test"
                },
                "buttons": [
                 {
                    "title": "Test weblink",
                    "openUriAction": { 
                        "uri":"https://www.eg.com"
                    }
                 }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: show the code where you do serialization

Comment: Just from a first glance without any actual code related to the serialization that this question is all about it looks like `fulfillmentMessages` has a length of 1 - a list or array with one element.

Comment: It also looks like we're missing a root element. I don't see a class with a property called `fulfillmentMessages` but it's in the JSON.

Comment: public class RootObject
{
    public List<FulfillmentMessage> fulfillmentMessages { get; set; }
}

Comment: Yes I didn't add the root object class but is exacly as @quaabaam point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you have a parent/root class where you are declaring something like this -

```
public class Root
{
    List<Fulfillmentmessage> fulfillmentMessages {get; set;}
}
```

And creating an object like this -

```
var root = new Root();
root.fulfillmentMessages = new List<Fulfillmentmessage>();
root.fulfillmentMessages.Add(new Fulfillmentmessage()); // <- Simple response
root.fulfillmentMessages.Add(new Fulfillmentmessage()); // <- Basic Card
```

However, as per your expected `json` your class structure(s) should be -

For `Fulfillmentmessage` class -

```
    public class Fulfillmentmessage
    {
        public string platform { get; set; }
        public Simpleresponses simpleResponses { get; set; }
        //public Text text { get; set; } <- No Text property here
        public string platform2 { get; set; }
        public Basiccard basicCard { get; set; }
    }
```

For `root` class -

```
public class Root
{
    List<object> fulfillmentMessages {get; set;} // Replaced Fulfillmentmessage with object
}
```

And create object like this -

```
var root = new Root();
root.fulfillmentMessages = new List<Fulfillmentmessage>();
root.fulfillmentMessages.Add(new Fulfillmentmessage()); // <- Simple response
root.fulfillmentMessages.Add(new Text()); // <- Text
root.fulfillmentMessages.Add(new Fulfillmentmessage()); // <- Basic Card
```

Comment: We were right about List<object>, that was the trick to represent json structure of fulfillmentMessages. Also I deleted platform2 property of Fulfillmentmessage Class and I  corrected my C# Class Text to achieve the desired output.

Comment: Also NullValueHandling.Ignore value, from Newtonsoft Library for avoiding output null values, is necessary.